# SwiftData migration ignores custom SchemaMigrationPlan

Tags: swiftui, core-data-migration, swift-data

I’m trying to migrate my Core Data app to use `SwiftData`. The goal is to completely replace Core Data.

While working on the new version, I’m also changing the database structure quite substantial (add entities, add attributes, rename attributes, add relationships, convert optional attributes to non-optionals, …). Therefore I have to use a custom migration. Following the WWDC talk I’ve added a `SchemaMigrationPlan` and as well as my `VersionedSchema`’s

**For some reason, it doesn’t even arrive at my custom migration. What am I doing wrong?**

The console doesn’t even print the `print()` statement in the custom migration.

#### App

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let container: ModelContainer
    let dataUrl = URL.applicationSupportDirectory.appending(path: "MyApp.sqlite")
    
    init() {
        let finalSchema = Schema([Loan.self, Item.self, Person.self, Location.self])
        
        do {
            container = try ModelContainer(
                for: finalSchema,
                migrationPlan: MyAppMigrationPlan.self,
                configurations: ModelConfiguration(url: dataUrl))
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize model container.")
        }
    }

    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(container)
    }
}
```

PS: I need to point to a custom url for my Core Data file, because I renamed my app a few years ago and didn’t change the name of the `NSPersistentContainer` back then.

#### Migration Plan

```
enum MyAppMigrationPlan: SchemaMigrationPlan {
    static var schemas: [any VersionedSchema.Type] {
        [SchemaV1.self, SchemaV2Step1.self, SchemaV2Step2.self]
    }
    
    
    // Migration Stages
    static var stages: [MigrationStage] {
        [migrateV1toV2Step1, migrateV1toV2Step2]
    }
    
    
    // v1 to v2 Migrations
    static let migrateV1toV2Step1 = MigrationStage.custom(
        fromVersion: SchemaV1.self,
        toVersion: SchemaV2Step1.self,
        willMigrate: nil,
        didMigrate: { context in
            print("Start migrating Core Data to SwiftData") // This isn’t printed in the Xcode debug console!?

            let loans = try? context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<SchemaV2Step1.Loan>())
            
            loans?.forEach { loan in
                // Mapping old optional attribute to new non-optional attribute
                loan.amount = Decimal(loan.price ?? 0.0)
                
                // doing other stuff
            }
            
            // Save all changes
            try? context.save()
        })

    
    // Adding new attributes and deleting old attributes replaced in step 1.
    static let migrateV1toV2Step2 = MigrationStage.lightweight(
        fromVersion: SchemaV2Step1.self,
        toVersion: SchemaV2Step2.self)
}
```

#### ModelSchema Excerpts

This schema mirrors my old Core Data stack and was created with Xcodes „Create SwiftData Code“ action. For some reason the Xcode generated code changes the `price` attribute to be a `Double`. The Core Data definition uses `Decimal` tough.

```
enum SchemaV1: VersionedSchema {
    static var versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(1, 0, 0)
    
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [Loan.self, Person.self]
    }

    // definition of all the model classes
    @Model
    final class Loan {
        var price: Double? = 0.0
        // …
    }

    final class Person {
        // …
    }
}
```

Besides other things, this schema introduces a new non-optional attribute `amount` that will replace `price`:

```
enum SchemaV2Step1: VersionedSchema {
    static var versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(1, 5, 0)
    
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [Loan.self, Person.self, Location.self]
    }

    // definition of all the model classes
    @Model
    final class Loan {
        var amount: Decimal = 0.0 // Will replace `price`
        var price: Double? = 0.0
        // …
    }

    final class Person {
        // …
    }

    // …
}
```

This final schema mostly deletes the old replaced attributes like mentioned above:

```
enum SchemaV2Step2: VersionedSchema {
    static var versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(2, 0, 0)
    
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [Loan.self, Item.self, Person.self, Location.self]
    }

    // definition of all the model classes
    @Model
    final class Loan {
        var amount: Decimal = 0.0
        // …
    }

    final class Person {
        // …
    }

    // …
}
```

To keep things shorter, I’ll not show all of the details for all of the schemas. The issue appears to be somewhere else anyway …

## Edit

Initially it crashed during the migration with:

```
UserInfo={entity=Loan, attribute=amount, reason=Validation error missing attribute values on mandatory destination attribute}
```

I’ve fixed that by setting a default value for all non-optionals. Thought the problem is that my custom migration code still isn’t executed and thus it simply uses all the default values instead of my custom mapping. Any ideas why?

Comment: I think you may need to post a minimal example of your Loan model, including any initializers.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi I’ve added the `amount` attribute as example. This is actually one of the many reasons I’m doing the custom migration, though there are many other things happening there as well.

Comment: Also `SchemaV1` basically mirrors the old Core Data stack and was created using the automatic Xcode migration code generation.

Comment: Shouldn’t amount be set to 0.0 since it’s not optional?

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi That’s probably it! ‍♂️ Just giving it a try right now, and it seems to work. I’m running into other problems, but at least it seems to work trough my custom migrations now!

Comment: Okay, I was too optimistic. The migration itself doesn’t crash anymore, which is a good step! So thanks for the hint. Though, it still skips my custom migration code …

Comment: What happens if you use default configuration for making ModelContainer? by passing [] instead of your custom configuration? I have the same issue. I don't know why ModelContainer won't read my migration plan with using my configuration. passing [] makes ModeContainer use a migration plan.

Comment: Ideally, ModelContainer visits `static var stages` property while it's initializing. you can make sure your migration plan has loaded with putting break point in that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it to solve this case.
Seems like it won't read your migration plan while passing the `Schema` parameter for using custom configuration.
(I could not figure out why it's happening)

Not using custom configuration gets `ModelContainer` to work well for migration.

Instead, we can use this initializer for `ModelContainer`.

```swift
public convenience init(for forTypes: PersistentModel.Type..., migrationPlan: (SchemaMigrationPlan.Type)? = nil, configurations: ModelConfiguration...) throws
```

### example code

```swift
let databasePath = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "database.store")

let configuration = ModelConfiguration(url: databasePath)

let container = try ModelContainer.init(
   for: Item.self, Foo.self, Bar.self,
   migrationPlan: Plan.self,
   configurations: configuration
)
```

To check if your migration has loaded correctly,

```
print(modelContainer.migrationPlan)
```

must print NOT nil.

Comment: Awesome – that finally brings me a step closer!!! Right now it crashes during the migration with the error: `Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134504 "Cannot use staged migration with an unknown model version."`. But at least it starts to work trough the breakpoints in my migration plan. That’s a start. 

Comment: Btw, what is supposed to be placed at the `for: ActiveScheme.Item.self` part? Like you can see in my initial question, I have multiple entities. If I can only put one there, which one should I pick?

Comment: Okay, I’ve finally figured out all issues that I had. Thanks again for figuring that strange error out!

**For others: keep an eye out to exactly match the Core Data types.** Xcode generated the SwiftData code using a `Double`, but it actually was a `Decimal` in Core Data, which needs to match.

Another error I had was `Unknown related type - Loan` when creating the new `Location` entities. I actually had to create an empty array instead of setting it to `nil`. More on that [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/fatal-error-when-creating-an-object-in-swiftdata/25303).

Comment: Another hint: it’s important to list all entities in the model container. Otherwise the previews will crash! It’s possible to simply separate them by comma like this: `try ModelContainer(for: Loan.self, Item.self, Person.self, Location.self, migrationPlan: Plan.self, configurations: configuration)`

Comment: I guess other initializers of ModelContaier do not work well with Migration seems SwiftData's bug. I could not understand why my migration plan did not work with that.