# Migrate Core Data to SwiftData in an App Group

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

I’m currently migrating my Core Data to SwiftData. After figuring out how to [correctly apply a migration plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77733798/swiftdata-migration-ignores-custom-schemamigrationplan) to evolve the data structure, I now want to move the database to App Groups. My goal is to support Widgets (and later iCloud sync).

**My old apps setup placed the Core Data file into the *Application Support* directory and saved it in a `.sqlite` file.**

I’ve already setup the App Group signing capability in Xcode. **But, now I can’t figure out how to find the old Core Data, migrate (and evolve) it in SwiftData, *and* place it in the app group.**

In [one of Apple’s example projects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/adopting_swiftdata_for_a_core_data_app#4295886) they note the following, but this doesn’t seem to work for me:

> This sample app uses App Groups to access shared containers and share data between the SwiftData widget extension and the Core Data host app. For an app that has the `App Groups Entitlement`, it persists the data store to the root directory of the app group container. For apps that evolve from a version that doesn’t have any app group container to a version that has one, SwiftData copies the existing store to the app group container.

### My Code

```swift
@main
struct MyAppName: App {
    let container: ModelContainer
    let dataUrl = URL.applicationSupportDirectory.appending(path: "Something.sqlite")
    
    init() {
        let configuration = ModelConfiguration(url: dataUrl)
        
        do {
            // Create SwiftData container with migration and custom URL pointing to legacy Core Data file
            container = try ModelContainer(
                for: Foo.self, Bar.self,
                migrationPlan: MigrationPlan.self,
                configurations: configuration)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize model container.")
        }
    }

    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(container)
    }
}
```

I’ve already tried to use the ModelConfiguration with a name, but it seems to only look for a `.store` file and thus doesn’t copy over the Core Data contents.

```swift
let fullSchema = Schema([Foo.self, Bar.self])
        
let configuration = ModelConfiguration("Something", schema: fullSchema)
```